# Is my Evaluation of $\mathcal{F}\{e^{-\alpha x^{2}}\}$, $\alpha>0$ correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, fourier-analysis

I wish to find the Fourier transform of $f(x):=e^{-\alpha x^{2}}$ without evaluating the contour integral in the complex plane. I worked on a different approach. First, observe that :
$$
f'(x)=2\alpha xf(x)
$$
I shall take the FT of both sides of the equality :
$$
2i\pi\xi\widehat{f}(\xi)=\frac{\alpha}{i\pi}\widehat{f}'(\xi)
$$
This is regroupled to give :
$$
\widehat{f}'(\xi)+\frac{2\pi^{2}}{\alpha}\xi\widehat{f}(\xi)=0
$$
Hence general solution is expected to be of the form :
$$\widehat{f}(\xi)=\phi(\xi)\exp\left(-\frac{\pi^{2}}{\alpha}\xi^{2}\right)$$
Is the evaluation so far correct? How should we reach that $\phi(\xi)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}$?

Comment: By the way, you should mention that $\alpha>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\widehat{f}(0)=\phi(0)\quad\implies\quad\widehat{f}(0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\alpha x^{2}}\;\text{d}x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}$$

Comment: But this is just $\phi(0)$ what about $\phi(\xi)$?

Comment: Notice how $\phi$ is independent of $\xi$. This could only be true if $\phi$ is a constant and indeed since $\phi'(\xi)=0\implies \phi(\xi)=\phi$ a constant.